# Clean up user tables from master in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I accidentally ran a create schema script using master and now I want to clean them up.  I'm on Win7, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.  I'm logged in SQL Server Management Studio with my local user account using Windows Authentication.  When I try to execute drop table statements in SQL Server Management Studio

```
DROP TABLE EVENT_CATEGORY_BRIDGE
GO 
DROP TABLE SUBSCRIBER_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_REFERENCE
GO
```

etc. I get

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1

Cannot drop the table 'SUBSCRIBER_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_REFERENCE', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

And if I right click and attempt to delete my junk tables in object browser I get a message saying the table was deleted successfully - but I can still see it in object browser, so I'm guessing I don't have permission to delete tables from master.

One problem I think is that my local user account on this machine is not an Administrator.  I'm not sure what I can do at this point, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the script you have ran?

Comment: It is just a series of drops and 'GO' like the snippet I posted (several dozen).  It is not more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query to return schema and table names that are not included in `master` by default:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName, name AS TableName
FROM master.sys.objects WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

**After inspecting the results**, run `DROP TABLE [<SchemaName>].[<TableName>]` for each that you'd like to drop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the delete tsql on the master database.  Try including the schema.

You need to refresh the object explorer after executing the deletes.